# Escribir en un archivo txt al ejecutar un php desde cmd

Tags: php, cmd

Tengo un archivo `php` el cual tiene que ejecutarse una ves al mes con esto no hay problema y un `txt` en el cual registro los eventos realizados y errores ocurridos si lo ejecuto **en el navegador todo perfecto** pero al ejecutar el archivo `php` mediante `cmd` este **no registra nada**, alguna sugerencia.

**funcion php para escribir en el txt**

```
function write_log($cadena,$tipo){
    $file = fopen("a08e2d073704db3ea107e3bbd81a8af1.txt", "a+");
    fwrite($file," [ ".date("d-m-Y H:i:s")." - $tipo ] ".$cadena . PHP_EOL);
    fclose($file);
}
```

**EDITO**

Al llamarlo desde el archivo .bat no realiza lo esperado

**Archivo .bat**

```
cd C:\xampp\php & php C:\xampp\htdocs\bienestar\admin\9b20185488dd94bdb4cc1b7c56494c1a.php
```

Comment: He realizado las pruebas y no tuve ningún problema, genera el archivo en caso no exista y agrega el texto que indicas. ¿De qué manera lo invocas desde CMD?

Comment: Hola @Davlio edite con el comando utilizado

Comment: Puedes indicar desde dónde ejecutas tu archivo BAT. Por ejemplo, ejecutando desde CMD: `X:\users\davlio\Desktop>cd ...[tu código de ejecución]` El archivo lo crea en la carpeta `X:\users\davlio\Desktop`.

Comment: Lo ejecuto como tarea programada y se encuentra en el mismo directorio que el php y txt

Comment: Igual, lo ejecuté como tarea programada y sin ningún problema. En todo caso tendrías que habilitar el historial de la tarea y verificar que no haya ningún error. A modo de prueba puedes modificar tu BAT a  `cd C:\xampp\php & start .` y verificar que al menos abra tu carpeta `C:\xampp\php`. El único problema que podrías tener, como en mi caso, fue el cambio de unidad con el comando CD, cambiar a la unidad `X:` y que considere correctamente dicha carpeta.

Comment: @Davlio tenias razon solo era un problema de ruta la cambie por ruta absoluta y funciono, al parecer `cmd` interpreta la ruta desde la raíz `C:\` por que hay se creaba el archivo pero al intentar modificarlo creo que lo tomaba desde otro lado